# How can I print both the key and the value in a map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

When I try to print with it.first, it.second it does not work,
Are these even valid functions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
map<string, int> workers;

workers["John"] = 1;
workers["Frank"] = 2;

for(map<string, int>::iterator it = workers.begin(); it != workers.end(); ++it) {
        cout<<it.first()<<":"<<it.second()<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I phrased that wrong, neither first or second work at all, How do I go about printing a map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`first` and `second` are no member functions, they are plain member objects:

```
cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << endl;
```

Note no parens, those are not function calls.

Comment: cout<<(*it).first<<":"<<(*it).second<<endl; would that be the proper way to write it? why is *it needed?

Comment: @SalRosa: Yeah, that would also work. I missed the fact that you were using iterators wrong as well

Comment: So iterator is a pointer or works like one and I'm derefing it for its value?

Comment: @SalRosa: Yes. You can think of iterators as a generalization of pointers.